# How to read CSV file from S3

Tags: csv, go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "path"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3iface"
)

var (
    // TOKEN = os.Getenv("TOKEN")
    svc s3iface.S3API
)

func main() {    
    // Panics if there is an error in creating session
    svc = s3iface.S3API(s3.New(session.Must(session.NewSession())))

    lambda.Start(Handler)
}

func Handler(evt events.S3Event) error {

    for _, rec := range evt.Records {

        key := rec.S3.Object.Key

        dir, file := path.Split(key)
        // Download the file from S3
        obj, err := svc.GetObject(&s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(rec.S3.Bucket.Name),
            Key:    aws.String(key),
        })
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("error in downloading %s from S3: %s\n", key, err)
        }

        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(obj.Body)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("error in reading file %s: %s\n", key, err)
        }

        reader := csv.NewReader(body)
        record, err := reader.ReadAll()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error", err)
        }

        for value := range record { // for i:=0; i<len(record)
            fmt.Println("", record[value])
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I am trying the parse the CSV file from S3, do something with each row, but I am getting

```
cannot use body (type []byte) as type io.Reader in argument to csv.NewReader:
    []byte does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)
```

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: `csv.NewReader` wants a reader. Just pass `obj.Body` to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error says:

> cannot use body (type []byte) as type io.Reader in argument to
>   csv.NewReader:
>     []byte does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)

because you are passing `[]byte` returned from the response to `csv.NewReader`

It is required to implement `io.Reader` by body to pass it as an argument to `csv.NewReader`. Since it takes `io.Reader` as an argument. Try to change your code as:

```
reader := csv.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(body))
record, err := reader.ReadAll()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error", err)
}
```

Also Since [aws.GetObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.GetObject) returns pointer to `GetObjectOutput` struct.

```
func (c *S3) GetObject(input *GetObjectInput) (*GetObjectOutput, error)
```

which itself implements Reader

```
type GetObjectOutput struct {
    ....
    // Object data.
    Body io.ReadCloser `type:"blob"`
    ....
}
```

so you can pass the returned body directly to csv.NewReader.

One more thing is you can go for Download Manager

> The s3manager package's Downloader provides concurrently downloading
>   of Objects from S3. The Downloader will write S3 Object content with
>   an io.WriterAt. Once the Downloader instance is created you can call
>   Download concurrently from multiple goroutines safely.

```
func (d Downloader) Download(w io.WriterAt, input *s3.GetObjectInput, options ...func(*Downloader)) (n int64, err error)
```

Download downloads an object in S3 and writes the payload into w using concurrent GET requests.

It is safe to call this method concurrently across goroutines.

```
// The session the S3 Downloader will use
sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())

// Create a downloader with the session and default options
downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess)

// Create a file to write the S3 Object contents to.
f, err := os.Create(filename)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to create file %q, %v", filename, err)
}

// Write the contents of S3 Object to the file
n, err := downloader.Download(f, &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(myBucket),
    Key:    aws.String(myString),
})
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to download file, %v", err)
}
```